# Performance Monitoring on Xilink SDK

Tags: performance, sdk, embedded, fpga, xilinx

I am using Zynq Ultrascale + ZU106 FPGA board and I'm trying to monitor cache misses when running my own code on it.
I'm running a very simple Z = Ax + B where A, B, and Z are 2D arrays.
I'm running this code because I know this will cause cache misses.
Following this link:
https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842421/Zynq+UltraScale+MPSoC+-+System+Performance+Modelling
I should be able to monitor the cache misses when I run my code on the board. When I run my code it doesn't catch it. Am I misunderstanding what this does? Or is there a better way to monitor cache misses?
I asked this question on Xilinx's forums but haven't heard back so I figured I ask here.